# How to use RE to find multiple balanced-size matches in a string?

Tags: python, regex

I've transformed a problem into a pattern matching problem, and tried to use RE to solve it.

The transformed problem: given a '0/1' string, like `s = '111100111111100111111001'`, try to find **exactly 3** matches of sub-string:

> a `'1'`, followed by arbitrary number of any characters, and then 2 consecutive
>   `'1's`, and the total size of the match is at least 4.

The above requirement could be coded as RE pattern: `'1.{1,}11'`. And the reverse pattern is also accepted:  `'11.{1,}1'`. Moreover, the interval of any 2 adjacent matches shall consume as least characters as possible.

This all translated as below code:

```
> import re
> s = '111100111111100111111001'
> p = '.*?(1.{1,}11|11.{1,}1).*?(1.{1,}11|11.{1,}1).*?(1.{1,}11|11.{1,}1).*?'
> ret = re.match(p, s)
> ret.groups()
```

The result:

```
> ('1111001111111', '1111', '11001')
```

This result is **good, but sub-optimal** in this sense: the length of each match shall be as balanced as possible.

A refined result shall be:

> ('1111001', '1111111', 11111001')

But how can I use RE to impose this constraint?

Comment: Your requirements are not clear because it is not possible to get the required output following them. *the length of each match shall be as balanced as possible* is not a "regex-friendly" requirement, BTW. It looks as if regex cannot help here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew,  yep, you probably are right on  'balanced size is not a "regex-friendly" requirement'. Actually I have tried a solution like the answer does,  but it is less efficient and thus I asked this question to find a more idiomatic RE solution. But it seems the requirement is probably beyond the capability of RE.

Comment: The length of the match is predetermined with quantifiers and backtracking mechanism that cannot be tweaked. Extract all possible matches and find "appropriate" ones using the language means.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of this:

```js
var input = '111100111111100111111001';

for (var i = input.length; i >= 4; i--) {
  var matches = input.match(new RegExp('.{' + i + '}', 'g'));
  
  var output = matches.filter(x => /^1.+1$/.test(x));
  
  if (output.length === 3) {
    console.log(output)
  }
}
```

> Starting with `1`, ending with `1` and having at least 4 characters

So, your example input should be matched, too. There are a lot of outputs can be matched as you can see.

```
1111111
^^^^
1111111
 ^^^^
1111111
  ^^^^
1111111
   ^^^^
1111111
^^^^^
1111111
 ^^^^^
1111111
  ^^^^^
1111111
^^^^^^
1111111
 ^^^^^^
1111111
^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the requirement a bit, from `at least 3 matches` to `exactly 3 matches`.   And I also tried some iterative search solution like yours, just to find it is not so efficient, so I asked this question, but it might turn out that some sort of iterative search solution is a must.

Comment: @larmbr I've updated my answer by changing the condition to `output.length === 3`. I'm not sure it solves your problem but you can start with it.